# Variation of parameters method for differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Change the variable $x=e^t$ and then find the general solution for  the following differential equation
$2x^2y''-6xy'+8y=2x+2x^2lnx$

Here's my take so far. It seems a little suspicious that i can factor out 2 and x first.
$x^2y''-3xy'+4y=x(ln(x)+1)$ and if we factor out $x^2$ now we end up with $y''-\frac{3}{x}y'+\frac{4}{x^2}y=\frac{xlnx+1}{x}$ (1) Therefore substituting $x=e^t$ (1) now becomes
$y''-\frac{3}{e^t}y'+\frac{4}{e^(2t)}y=\frac{e^tt+1}{e^t}$ We need constant coefficients in order to use the variation of parameters method am i right? Please help.

Comment: You are to find a completely new equation for $u(t)=y(e^t)$. It happens but is largely wrong that $u$ gets also named $y$. A strict distinction of coordinate variables and functions between these variables can also help. // Or apply the solution mechanism for Euler-Cauchy DE.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340285/solve-x3yxy-y-x-lnx/4340286#4340286

Comment: Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After change the variable $x=e^t$ we get
$$y''-4y'+4y=te^{2t}+e^t$$
Then
$$y=\frac{t^3e^{2t}+6e^t}{6}+(C_1+C_2t)e^{2t}=$$
$$=\frac{x^2\ln^3x+6x}{6}+(C_1+C_2\ln x)x^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!